# Where shall i put woocommerce rest api library files

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have no idea how to work with WooCommerce library files, where to paste those files and where to paste the code.

I have found the following code :

```
<?php

require_once( 'lib/woocommerce-api.php' );

$options = array(
    'debug'           => true,
    'return_as_array' => false,
    'validate_url'    => false,
    'timeout'         => 30,
    'ssl_verify'      => false,
);

try {

    $client = new WC_API_Client( 'http://your-store-url.com', 'ck_enter_your_consumer_key', 'cs_enter_your_consumer_secret', $options );

    } catch ( WC_API_Client_Exception $e ) {

    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    echo $e->getCode() . PHP_EOL;

    if ( $e instanceof WC_API_Client_HTTP_Exception ) {

        print_r( $e->get_request() );
        print_r( $e->get_response() );
    }
}
```

But still have no idea, where to put this code,  uploads/add other library files.

I am using [REST API library](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library) by Kloon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the file within your theme on FTP. In order for it to work with wooCommerce and access the order data you want on your websites theme. So on ftp your path will look something like:

```
public_html/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/...place the lib folder here.
```

once you have added the folder, you will notice your path for require is:

```
require_once( 'lib/woocommerce-api.php' );
```

this means the file accessing the path; where you are writing your code and testing, is not within the lib folder. So you can either create a file outside the lib folder and place it in your theme or, for the sake of organization, create a folder called wooAPI and then place everything in there:

**this folder is in -> public_html/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/

wooApi/lib/...files

wooAPI/....testFile that calls Lib

then you can run a test to see if your function exists as expected:

```
<?php
if( function_exists( 'some_function' ) )
{
   // Require/include stuff here
}
```

If it does you are good to begin your work in the API.

If it is still not working you can place the files directly within your themes woocommerce folder to ensure they load:

```
public_html/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/woocommerce/...your folder
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you check this post to put the library files in wordpress...

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31726/where-to-put-third-party-php-library

Comment: Link-only answers are not helpful when the content moves or changes. Include the relevant parts directly in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the file "lib" into the same folder as the php page you are trying to test on. For example:

```
some-folder/
     -lib
     -test.php
```

So now if you paste the code in your question into test.php, change the dummy data to be your own, you should be good to go.
Where you see at the top of the file it is requiring another file that has to have the correct path in it. If you were to move the lib folder then your path needs to be correct when calling it.